# Why do I get "Undefined mixin 'border-radius'" in Compass?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

In my Compass the top file has lines which include necessary plugins:

```
@import "compass";
@import "rgbapng";
@import "compass/css3";
@import "config";    // file that has my variables
```

But during compilation of a file that has `@include border-radius($box-radius-small);` errors out saying `Undefined mixin 'border-radius'` and `Undefined variable: "$box-radius-small".` - both of which should be included already!

Can anyone please help with this issue?

**PS my packages are:**

Compass 0.12.2 (Alnilam)
Sass 3.2.7 (Media Mark)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just place the following import at the top of your scss file

```
@import "compass/css3";
```

Features of css3 :: http://compass-style.org/examples/compass/css3/

There are many other imports available out there...and you can create your own if you find yourself re-using blocks of css often enough to warrant the extra effort.

Answer (score 8):

Try to `@import` "compass" and your "config" variable sheet in every stylesheet that uses the mixins or variables.

Comment: Well this is what I do in the mean time but it seems to me to be a bug. I guess I have to ping them on Github.