# Gulp can't seem to find compass mixins

Tags: sass, gulp, compass-sass, gulp-sass

I am trying out gulp as an alternative build tool to Grunt, to compile my scss to css, as I have heard it can be much faster.

I having problems doing even a basic compile of my scss files. I have tried using the **gulp-sass**, **gulp-ruby-sass** and **gulp-compass** plugins for gulp and I get pretty much the same error message every time:

```
error screen.scss (Line 2 of _grid.scss: Undefined mixin 'box-sizing'.)
```

So it looks like it is falling down as soon as it hits a compass mixin. I have ruby installed on my PC with compass version 1.0.0.alpha.19 and sass version 3.3.7.

Here is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
compass = require('gulp-compass'),
sass = require('gulp-ruby-sass');

gulp.task('compass', function() {
gulp.src('../sass/UK/screen.scss')
.pipe(compass({
    css: '../css',
    sass: '../sass',
  sourcemap: true,
  style: 'compressed'
}))
.pipe(gulp.dest('../css/UK/screen.css'));
});

gulp.task('sass', function () {
  gulp.src('../sass/UK/**/*.scss')
      .pipe(sass({ style: 'compressed', sourcemap: true }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest('../css/UK'));
});
```

Any ideas how I tell it where my copy of compass is installed? I thought it was installed globally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Undefined mixin 'border-radius'" in Compass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422098/why-do-i-get-undefined-mixin-border-radius-in-compass)

Comment: I have the lines:


*@import "compass/reset";*

*@import "compass/css3";*

in my _base.scss file which is called into my screen.scss (the one that gets compiled to screen.css) before my _grid.scss file where the problem is occuring, so i don't think it is that.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17976140/false-positive-undefined-variable-error-when-compiling-scss

Comment: The `@import compass/css3` should include the box-sizing mixin, so something else is wrong. Try taking gulp out of the equation and just compiling via Compass. From there, narrow down which parts of your Sass files are missing the mixin.

Comment: Hi Katie, tried to compile the sass with gulp just using `sass screen.scss screen.css` and i get an error: `Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/reset.`. So it looks like compass/sass are the problems not gulp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You right, `compass` should be installed globally on your system to get this work, at least easily. I recommend you to uninstall sass and compass to get something clean using

```
gem uninstall sass && gem uninstall compass
```

And then re-install them with :

```
gem install sass
gem install compass --pre
```

And after you can define a gulp task like so

```
gulp.task('compass', function () {

  return gulp.src('../sass/UK/screen.scss')
    .pipe(sass({ compass: true, sourcemap: true, style: 'compressed' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../css/UK/screen.css'));

});
```

Comment: That's exactly what i did when i installed compass and sass (well i didn't need to install sass individually as it is installed as a dependency of compass). Now if i do `compass -v` or `sass -v` anywhere on the c: drive where it is installed it returns the version number so it is something else.

Comment: The option `--pre` of the `gem install compass` is really important, have you done that ?

Comment: yep `gem install compass --pre` exactly as you say. I have compass version 1.0.0.alpha.19 installed and sass 3.3.7 installed as a dependency of that compass install.

Comment: Ha, me being stupid. I added in compass: true and it worked fine. Thanks for your help Aperçu.

Comment: It happens, don't blame you, glad that helped ! :)

Answer (score 5):

There is bit of confusion around using Compass with Gulp. There are three gulp extensions: **gulp-ruby-sass**, **gulp-compass** and **gulp-sass**. They basically do the same thing. They compile SASS to CSS. But:

- [gulp-ruby-sass](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-ruby-sass): Is a wrapper around command line tool: **sass** that comes with the language. It is written in Ruby and it is [installed via gem](http://sass-lang.com/install) - Ruby's package manager.
- [gulp-compass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-compass): Is a wrapper around command line tool: **compass** that comes with [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) framework. It is written in Ruby and it is also [installed via gem](http://compass-style.org/install/). However, Compass is just a framework. It consists of SASS files only. All that *compass* command do, is setting paths to framework SASS files to **sass** command so that Compass dependencies are being resolved.
- [gulp-sass](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass): Is a wrapper around tool: **node-sass** which is Node.JS binding to [libsass](https://github.com/sass/libsass): a C/C++ implementation of a Sass compiler.

The above answers did not work for me since I am using **gulp-sass**. It does not see Compass files out of the box. So first I installed [compass-mixins](https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins) (SASS files of Compass framework) and later I imported them with [compass-importer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compass-importer):

```
import compass from 'compass-importer';
import sass from 'gulp-sass';

gulp.task('styles', function () {
  return gulp.src(config.styles.src)
    .pipe(sass({
      importer: compass
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.styles.dest))
})
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more? Where is this code written - inside gulpfile.js?  I have the exact issue which falls in the category you described but I cannot figure out how to use `compass-mixins`. I was using the `gulp-saas` part from [this resource](https://github.com/haithembelhaj/compass-importer).

Comment: Ok, I figured it out, I had to use `@import "compass";` in my .scss (saas source file) as the first line and then everything fell in place. Logging this here just in case it helps anyone facing similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that gulp-ruby-sass has a new syntax which should look like:

```
gulp.task('compass', function () 
  sass(../sass/UK/screen.scss, { compass: true, sourcemap: true, style: 'compressed' })
  .pipe(gulp.dest('../css/UK/screen.css'));
});
```