# Gulp: trying to import compass mixins

Tags: sass, gulp, compass-sass

I have just followed [this](http://www.zingdesign.com/the-sass-and-compass-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/) tutorial without problems, to start using SASS. As you can see it includes a part where it is using **compass mixins**. I have compiled `.scss` files including `@import compass/css3/box-sizing` without problems.

Now I want to compile my `.scss` files, but using Gulp. So I have followed [this](http://knpuniversity.com/screencast/gulp/sass) tutorial. So now I have these files:

```
//src/DefaultBundle/Resources/public/assets/css/main.scss
form {
  span {
    color: red;
  }
}

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src('src/DefaultBundle/Resources/public/assets/css/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('web/css'));
});
```

So when I run `$ gulp` as the latter tutorial says, I get the `.css` file.

**The problem**: if I add **`@import compass/css/box-sizing`** at the top of my `.scss file`, I get this error when running `$ gulp`:

```
[13:12:01] Working directory changed to /var/www/my_project
[13:12:01] Using gulpfile /var/www/my_project/gulpfile.js
[13:12:01] Starting 'default'...
[13:12:01] Finished 'default' after 5.37 ms

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: src/DefaultBundle/Resources/public/assets/css/main.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass/css3/box-sizing
       Parent style sheet: stdin
        on line 2 of stdin
>> @import "compass/css3/box-sizing";
   ^

    at options.error (/var/www/my_project/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:277:32)
```

Im on Ubuntu 15.

Comment: You aren't *using* Compass, why would you think you could import mixins from Compass?   The Gulp tutorial you linked to only shows you how to use it with Sass, not Compass.

Comment: This might help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745932/gulp-cant-seem-to-find-compass-mixins?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48603409/6389945). You can also use `includePaths` option to add any partials:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.src('src/DefaultBundle/Resources/public/assets/css/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass({
             includePaths: ['./node_modules/compass-mixins/lib', './another/partials/location']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('web/css'));
});
```