# Compass mixins with Gulp

Tags: css, node.js, gulp, workflow, compass

Is there a way to use Compass mixins with Gulp ? How to use them ?

I tried to use Compass on my Gulp project but each time I get an error with my Compass @import.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

It's even simpler to use [compass-importer](https://github.com/haithembelhaj/compass-importer). Install it with

`npm install --save-dev compass-importer`

require it in your gulpfile.js and add `importer: compass` to *sass* options

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var sass = require('gulp-sass')
var compass = require('compass-importer')

gulp.task('sass', function()
{
return gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')
  .pipe(sass({ importer: compass }).on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));

});
```

Comment: This worked great! I had an old project and wanted to get away from compass.

Comment: @NickStees Compass has been depreciated for at least 2 years now, so it's a must to switch to something much faster like node-sass/gulp-sass

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install the **[npm compass-mixins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/compass-mixins)** package, as so:

### `npm install compass-mixins --save-dev`

Then, add a custom pipe for it, something similar to this:

```
.pipe(function() {
    return $.if('*.scss', $.sass({
      outputStyle: 'nested', 
      includePaths: [
       './node_modules/compass-mixins/lib'
      ]
    }));
  })
```

More detailed info in **[this thread.](https://discourse.roots.io/t/adding-compass-to-gulpfile-js/3210/3)**