# Can't import compass' mixins with foundation 6 and gulp

Tags: sass, gulp, zurb-foundation

I followed the [foundation tutorial](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html) to create a new project. So I compile and watch the sass files with `foundatoin watch` which compile my files and stream the output to the localhost but I get this error when I am trying to import compass by typing `@import "compass";` :

```
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    src\assets\scss\app.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: compass
       Parent style sheet: C:/Users/Kevin/Dropbox/Work/Perso/2016_01_KMStudio Site/km_website/src/assets/scss/app.scss
        on line 7 of src/assets/scss/app.scss
>> @import "compass";
```

I am really a newbie to `gulp`, `gem` and all this stuff, so I tried to add `compass` by running `bower install compass` but this doesn't help. I already installed `compass` with `gem` by running `gem install compass`and this doesn't fix the problem.

So I searched to modify the gulp file, but I don't know anything about it, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24745932/gulp-cant-seem-to-find-compass-mixins#) and I tried to add `.pipe(sass({ compass: true, sourcemap: true, style: 'compressed' }))` into my `sass` pipe. And this leads me to this error:

```
 'sass' errored after 7.62 s
[19:33:49] TypeError: Cannot read property 'isFile' of undefined
    at isFile (C:\Users\Kevin\Dropbox\Work\Perso\2016_01_KMStudio Site\km_website\node_modules\gulp-load-plugins\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:12:20)
    at loadAsFileSync (C:\Users\Kevin\Dropbox\Work\Perso\2016_01_KMStudio Site\km_website\node_modules\gulp-load-plugins\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:42:17)
    at loadAsDirectorySync (C:\Users\Kevin\Dropbox\Work\Perso\2016_01_KMStudio Site\km_website\node_modules\gulp-load-plugins\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:68:16)
    at loadNodeModulesSync (C:\Users\Kevin\Dropbox\Work\Perso\2016_01_KMStudio Site\km_website\node_modules\gulp-load-plugins\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:77:21)
    at Function.module.exports [as sync] (C:\Users\Kevin\Dropbox\Work\Perso\2016_01_KMStudio Site\km_website\node_modules\gulp-load-plugins\node_modules\resolve\lib\sync.js:27:17)
    at requireFn (C:\Users\Kevin\Dropbox\Work\Perso\2016_01_KMStudio Site\km_website\node_modules\gulp-load-plugins\index.js:64:25)
    at Object.defineProperty.get [as sourcemaps] (C:\Users\Kevin\Dropbox\Work\Perso\2016_01_KMStudio Site\km_website\node_modules\gulp-load-plugins\index.js:103:41)
    at sass (C:/Users/Kevin/Dropbox/Work/Perso/2016_01_KMStudio Site/km_website/gulpfile.babel.js:79:11)
    at sass (C:/Users/Kevin/Dropbox/Work/Perso/2016_01_KMStudio Site/km_website/gulpfile.babel.js:80:11)
    at sass (C:/Users/Kevin/Dropbox/Work/Perso/2016_01_KMStudio Site/km_website/gulpfile.babel.js:80:11)
```

Since I know nothing about gulp, streaming and sass compiling, I am wondering if someone could help me to add compass' mixins to my project. I am on Windows.

Comment: Foundation 6 doesn't use compass. You don't need to `@import 'compass';`

Comment: I did that, and this returns me the first code I wrote. @GavinBruce

Comment: Did you have foundation 5 installed? http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html recommends to uninstall it. `gem uninstall foundation` Then install f6. `sudo npm install --global foundation-cli`

Comment: How would it help ? Compass is not with foundation 6 by default when you install it. If I create a project with Foundation 5 it's working perfectly. @GavinBruce

Comment: Have you installed https://github.com/sass/node-sass The http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sass.html page says: Foundation for Sites can be compiled with Ruby Sass and libsass. We tend to stick to the latest versions of both compilers when possible. Our documentation and starter project are compiled with node-sass, a Node port of libsass. We recommend these versions of either compiler:

Ruby Sass 3.4+
node-sass 3.4.2+ (libsass 3.3.2) @kevin-m