# Sass compiler throws 'undefined mixin' error when mixins are kept in seperate folder

Tags: sass, mixins

Here is the screenshot of my website structure.
[image: Screenshot of project structure]

In my mixins file, I have created all the necessary sass mixins.

I have created this mixin for border radius:

```
 @mixin border-radius($radius) {
  -webkit-border-radius: $radius;
     -moz-border-radius: $radius;
      -ms-border-radius: $radius;
       -o-border-radius: $radius;
          border-radius: $radius;
}
```

Now when I try to use this for my button class in _button.scss in modules folder , I get undefined variable error. Whereas when I use the same mixin in the _button.scss file itself, I don't get any error.

in my _button.scss file i have included the mixin as under

```
button{
    background-color: $theme-color;
    border: 0px solid;
    padding: 0.7rem 3rem;
    @include border-radius(2rem);

}
```

What is the issue exactly. I want to keep all my mixins in a seperate file to keep the structure neat.

Comment: Sass doesn't throw this error for no reason, and it's not because the mixin is "in a separate folder".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get "Undefined mixin 'border-radius'" in Compass?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422098/why-do-i-get-undefined-mixin-border-radius-in-compass)

Comment: Please note: Always declare mixins before using them to avoid the ' undefined mixins ' error. So make sure to use include after the mixin is declared not before that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you have to include the mixin with @include or @import

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/mixin

Comment: when I am including the mixin in the same file it works well .. 
but when the mixin is in a seperate _mixin.scss file in seperate modules folder, it doesn't work even after using the "@include" statement. Why so?

Comment: $project-path: absolute-path(".."); see if setting the project path so the compass works properly

Comment: the link says page not found

Comment: also, worth noticing, you have to declare the mixin before calling it (that worked for me, coming from Google, hehe)

Answer (score 13):

Ad `as *` end of line

Example:

```
@use  './mix' as *;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This was it for me

Comment: Could you please add further clarification to your answer?

Comment: This is the only correct answer

Answer (score 7):

Only answering because I got the same error for a different reason.

The solution for me was to reorder my imports. As it turns out I was referencing a mixin that wasn't imported yet. Check to be sure you aren't using a mixin prior to it's being imported.

Comment: the same for me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

as Waseem Wisa said you add @use 'mix' as *;
or
you can edit your file like this:
'''

```
@use 'mix';
button{
    background-color: $theme-color;
    border: 0px solid;
    padding: 0.7rem 3rem;
    @include mix.border-radius(2rem);

}
```

'''

or add index.scss file to your scss folder then forward all module files in it like :
_index.scss (this is file name)

```
`forward 'mix';`
```

after that add this file to your main.scss

```
`@use 'index' as *;`
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Brian's answer make sure you import the `_mixins.scss` file in the main sass file.

On the top simply do this.

```scss
// style.scss
@import "mixins";
```

This will fix the undefined error.

Answer (score 1):

First import the mixin sass file in your style.scss file. Be sure to import the file first before importing the globals and variables file.
For example like this,
`@import "_variables";`
`@import "_mixins";`
`@import "_globals";`
`@import "_header";`